# Can I return a game I activated through Steam and bought from GameFly, and get a refund if I have never downloaded it to my PC?

Tags: steam

I recently bought a game though GameFly, and I never actually downloaded the game. Now I would like to get a refund. May I return and get a refund, and if so then how do I go about getting my refund?

If not, what other alternatives are there? Such as Steam trading, etc. I just want my money back, or most of it.

Another possible alternative would be to exchange it for a different game. Can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close your question. This question is about a business, not games.

Comment: [We've opened a meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/are-questions-about-game-companies-policies-on-topic) discussion on this and similiar questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GameFly seems to pass the buck and [their FAQ says](http://www.gamefly.com/support/gameflydigital/):

> Your game activation is supported by your Game Publisher.  GameFly Customer Support does not have access to assist you with this activation.

However, if it's a Steam game, and you activated the game on your Steam account, there's no going back - it's permanently yours.  You can't trade the game if you've activated it to your account.  Trading only works with gifts that you've not activated on your account already.

I think the exception to this rule is in European countries, there might be a short-term "out" due to the [laws being different](http://europa.eu/rapid/pressReleasesAction.do?reference=MEMO/11/675&type=HTML) there.  I don't live in Europe so I can't really comment on how this would change the situation.  I also don't know how the GameFly involvement would complicate things, but I'd suggest contacting Steam Support if you're a European gamer.

Comment: Even with the EU regulations, you still can't get a refund on Steam games (other than pre-orders) from EU countries.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but a good answer nonetheless. Thank you!